# JAVA.UTIL.NoSuchElementException ERROR (SITUATION BASED)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I am having trouble with this program:

The history teacher at your school needs help grading a True/False test. The
students’ IDs and test answers are stored in a file. The first entry in the file
contains the answers to the test in the form:
TFFTFFTTTTFFTFTFTFTT
Every other entry in the file is the student’s ID, followed by a blank,
followed by the student’s response. For example, the entry:
ABC54301 TFTFTFTT TFTFTFFTTFT
indicates that the student’s ID is ABC54301 and the answer to question 1 is True,
the answer to question 2 is False, and so on. This student did not answer
question 9. The exam has 20 questions, and the class has more than 150 students.
Each correct answer is awarded two points, each wrong answer gets -1 point,
and no answer gets 0 points. Write a program that processes the test data. The
output should be the student’s ID, followed by the answers, followed by the test
score, followed by the test grade. Assume the following grade scale: 90% - 100%, A; 80% - 89.99%, B; 70% - 79.99%, C; 60% - 69.99%, D; and 0% - 59.99%, F.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Assignment6
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
                        throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("student.txt"));
        
        String id, gracias;
        String denada ="";
        int score = 0;
        double percent;
        char grade;

        char[] orig = new char[20];
        char[] sc = new char[20];

        for(int i=0 ; i<20 ; i++)
        {
            gracias = inFile.next();
            orig[i] = gracias.charAt(i);
        }
        inFile.nextLine();
        while(inFile.hasNext())
        {
            id = inFile.next();

            for(int i=0 ; i<20 ; i++)
            {
                sc[i] = inFile.next().charAt(i);
            
                if(sc[i] == orig[i])
                    score++;
                else if(sc[i] != orig[i] && sc[i] != ' ')
                    score--;
                denada += sc[i];
            }
            inFile.nextLine();

            percent = (score/20)*100;

            if(percent >= 90 && percent <= 100)
                    grade = 'A';
            else if(percent >= 80 && percent <= 89.99)
                    grade = 'B';
            else if(percent >= 70 && percent <= 79.99)
                    grade = 'C';
            else if(percent >= 60 && percent <= 69.99)
                    grade = 'D';
            else
                    grade = 'F';
                                         
            System.out.printf("%-8s%-8s%-2d%-2c%n",id,denada,score,grade);
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
}
```

I have tried this but it shows me following errors

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at Assignment6.main(Assignment6Java.java:19)
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated...THANKS

Comment: Have you read the javadoc for the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception at line #19.

```
gracias = inFile.next();
```

java.util.Scanner.next() method returns the next token. It returns 'NoSuchElementException' when no more tokens are available

Have you checked the contents of the file? Ensure that the file is not blank.
Also, you should ensure that the next token exists instead of blindly using the for loop.

Just a heads up -

```
String s="TTFFT"
```

has only one token, while

```
String s="TTF FT"
```

has two tokens